# How should I approach debugging NULL COM pointer access errors?

Tags: pywinauto

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I need to automate a proprietary application for a client. I've been able to run some of the example code [here](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#automate-notepad-at-the-command-line) successfully (i.e. pywinauto works on notepad). For the proprietary app, it seems like any eventual call of `elements_from_uia_array(ptrs_array, cache_enable)` fails with the same NULL COM pointer access error for this app specifically. How should I approach solving this problem?

Context:

1. Environment: Windows 10, Python 3.6.2, pywinauto-0.6.3
2. Observations: no NULL COM errors when automating Google Chrome & Notepad

Here is the stack trace I got when trying to create a wrapper object from a WindowsSpecification. `print_control_identifiers()` on any top level window also gives me the same error.

```
>>> test = actual_window.child_window(auto_id="_buttonFindStudent",control_type="Button")
>>> test
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x000002277006DC50>
>>> profit = test.wrapper_object()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
profit = test.wrapper_object()
  File "C:\Users\SK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 254, in wrapper_object
ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Users\SK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 245, in __resolve_control
criteria)
  File "C:\Users\SK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 425, in wait_until_passes
func_val = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\SK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 209, in __get_ctrl
ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
  File "C:\Users\SK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 84, in find_element
elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 214, in find_elements
depth=depth)
  File "C:\Users\SK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_element_info.py", line 283, in descendants
elements = self._get_elements(IUIA().tree_scope["descendants"], cond, cache_enable)
  File "C:\Users\SK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_element_info.py", line 262, in _get_elements
return elements_from_uia_array(ptrs_array, cache_enable)
  File "C:\Users\SK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_element_info.py", line 48, in elements_from_uia_array
for n in range(ptrs.Length):
ValueError: NULL COM pointer access
```

Comment: Looks similar to this issue: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/296 Going to fix it soon (this month).

Comment: Can you try the fix from [this branch](https://github.com/airelil/pywinauto/archive/dev.zip) ?

Comment: Will try the fix and let you know!

Comment: @Raybov; the fix from that branch seems to work; I'm now getting the normal exceptions: "ElementNotFoundError"; which is expected; Thanks! Do you know when we can expect the changes to be merged?

Comment: We're planning to release 0.6.4 in October (hope before 10th of October but there is no hard deadline).

Answer (score 2):

[pywinauto==0.6.4](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/releases/tag/0.6.4) fixes this issue (just posted on PyPI). Sorry for long waiting. Just upgrade it by `pip install -U pywinauto`.